# Crawl a website and its external links recursively to create a graph for a data analysis project n Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, scrapy

I have this project that I'm trying to put together for a data analytics experiment. I have a pipeline in mind but I don't exactly know how to go on about getting the data I need.
I want to crawl a website and find all internal and external link, separate them and crawl the external links recursively until it reaches a certain depth. I want to do this to create a graph of all the connections for a website, to then use centrality algorithms to find the center node and proceed from there. 
Ideally, I would like to use python 2 for this project.
I had a look at scrapy, beautiful soup and other libraries but it is all quite confusing.

Any help and/or advice would be much appreciated on crawling and creating the graph especially

Thank you

EDIT:

I'm trying to implement the solution you suggested and with the code below, I can see in the debug information that it is finding the links but either they are not being saved in the LinkList class or I'm extracting them wrong and they are getting filtered.

Any suggestions?

```
class LinkList(Item):
    url = Field()

class WebcrawlerSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'webcrawler'
    allowed_domains = ['https://www.wehiweb.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.wehiweb.com']

rules = (
    Rule(LxmlLinkExtractor(allow=()), callback='parse_obj', follow=True),
)

def parse_obj(self,response):
    item = LinkList()
    item['url'] = []
    for link in LxmlLinkExtractor(allow=(),deny = self.allowed_domains).extract_links(response):
        item['url'].append(link.url)
        yield item

def main():
    links = LinkList()
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(WebcrawlerSpider)
    process.start()
    print(links.items())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

Scrapy should work fine for this. Most people use it to extract data from websites (scraping), but it can be used for simple crawling as well.

In scrapy you have spiders that crawl websites and follow links. A scrapy project can consist of many spiders, but in the standard setup each spider will have its own queue and do its own task.

As you described your use case, I would recommend two separate scrapy spiders:

- one for onsite scraping with a `allowed_domains` setting only for this domain and a very high or even 0 (=infinite) `MAX_DEPTH` setting, so that it will crawl the whole domain
- one for offsite scraping with an empty `allowed_domains` (will allow all domains) and a low `MAX_DEPTH` setting, so that it will stop after certain number of hops

From your `parse` method's perspective scrapy has a concept of `Request` and `Item`. You can return both `Request` and `Item` from the method that parses your response:

- requests will trigger scrapy to visit a website and in turn call your `parse` method on the result
- items allow you to specify the results you define for your project

So whenever you want to follow a link you will `yield` a `Request` from your parse method. And for all results of your project you will yield `Item`.

In your case, I'd say that your `Item` is something like this:

```
class LinkItem(scrapy.Item):
    link_source = scrapy.Field()
    link_target = scrapy.Field()
```

This will allow you to return the item `link_source="http://example.com/", link_target="http://example.com/subsite"` if you are on page `http://example.com/` and found a link to `/subsite`:

```
def parse(self, response):
    # Here: Code to parse the website (e.g. with scrapy selectors 
    # or beautifulsoup, but I think scrapy selectors should
    # suffice

    # after parsing, you have a list "links"
    for link in links:
        yield Request(link)  # make scrapy continue the crawl

        item = LinkItem()
        item['link_source'] = response.url
        item['link_target'] = link
        yield item  # return the result we want (connections in link graph)
```

You might see that I did not do any depth checking etc. You don't have to do this manually in your `parse` method, scrapy ships with `Middleware`. One of the middlewares is called `OffsiteMiddleware` and will check if your spider is allowed to visit specific domains (with the option `allowed_domains`, check the scrapy tutorials). And other one is `DepthMiddleware` (also check the tutorials).

These results can be written anywhere you want. Scrapy ships with something called `feed exports` which allow you to write data to files. If you need something more advanced, e.g. a database, you can look at scrapy's `Pipeline`.

I currently do not see the need for other libraries and projects apart from scrapy for your data collection.

Of course when you want to work with the data, you might need specialized data structures instead of plain text files.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will set up a full on scrapy project and try to implement what you said. I really appreciate the help :) btw I up voted but don't have enough reputation to show :)